# Бэкап Ubuntu для восстановления

Tags: linux, ubuntu, резервное-копирование

Установил себе Ubuntu и все необходимое ПО и настроил. Теперь хотелось бы создать точку для восстановления.

Чтобы в будущем смог быстро восстановить (откатить).

Подскажите пожалуйста,

1. правильно понимаю, что если система сломается так, что нельзя будет зайти в систему, то в любом случае, можно будет загрузиться через liveCD и забрать свои данные на съемный носитель?
2. какие популярные программы есть для создания точек восстановления? как они работают? Создают снимок полностью всей системы? или только системных файлов?  При восстановлении системы ПО установленное позднее точки восстановления будут удалены?
3. и правильно ли понимаю (где-то слышал), что я могу сам делать резервную копию обычным копированием, закинув на переносной жесткий диск папку `/home` ?
   Если это так, то при восстановлении разве не могут быть случаи, когда некоторые приложения часть своих файлов не в `/home` хранят,и из-за этого не будет работать ?

Comment: Просто отдавайте себе отчёт о том, что вы делаете, используя команду sudo и никакие бекапы не будут нужны. Без прав рута сломать систему практически невозможно. Насчёт home всё верно. Пользовательские конфиги хранятся только там и больше нигде, по этому бекапить системный раздел нет никакого смысла. Его проще переустановить, подключив старый home.

Comment: В Ubuntu, [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) в помощь если надо с GUI

Comment: если шаришь командной строке то очень комфортно использовать `dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=8096 | gzip -9cf > sda1.dd-image.gz`. Займёт 6Гиг.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf **никакие бекапы не будут нужны** - это круто!!! Как много, оказывается, в мире идиотов сисадминов, которые регулярно бэкапят системы! В самых, казалось-бы, уважаемых фирмах... :-)

Comment: @Sergey если вы считаете меня идиотом, то аргументируйте пожалуйста вашу точку зрения. То что в каких-то там уважаемых фирмах работают идиоты-сисадмины, это наверно печально, но меня не особо волнует.

Comment: @Sergey под никакими я имел ввиду никакие системные, а не вообще никакие :) Бекапы персональных данных конечно же нужны!

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf *аргументируйте пожалуйста вашу точку зрения* - зачем? Я делаю бэкапы (полные) каждую неделю, а частичные - каждый день. Вы считает, что это лишнее. Ну так я Вас же не заставляю следовать моему примеру. На нет и суда нет...

Comment: @Sergey существует только один случай, когда системный бекап необходим (и я лично с ним не сталкивался никогда) - если ваша система настолько нестабильна, что вам приходится восстанавливать её по нескольку раз в год (чисто ради экономии времени). В любом другом случае это не нужно, поскольку вместо восстановления лучше ставить новую версию дистрибутива (если конечно у вас не роллинг-релиз).

Answer (score -1):

> 1. в любом случае, можно будет загрузиться через liveCD и забрать свои данные на съемный носитель?

Да. Но: Вы собираетесь делать бэкап на тот же диск, на котором крутится рабочая система? Не самое хорошее решение... Даже если у Вас нет доступа ни на какой сервер, установите на Вашем хосте **отдельный** винт под бэкап. Тогда, даже если у Вас сгорит материнка, вы сможете достать винт, установить его на другой комп и достать из него всё, что нужно.

> 2. какие популярные программы есть для создания точек восстановления?

Вообще-то, если речь идёт об обычном десктопе, то делать копию **всей** системы особого смысла нет. Собственно саму системы Вы легко и быстро восстановите из репозитария. Это гораздо проще, чем делать копию, а потом восстанавливать с неё.  На самом деле, вам нужно восстановить только каталог */home/my_name* и ничего больше.

Но даже в этом каталоге нет никакого смысла восстанавливать папки *tmp* и им подобные. Очень мало смысла восстанавливать всякие кэши браузера и разных IDE, объектные файлы и прочие промежуточные результаты компиляции программ. В бэкапе должны лежать только действительно **нужные** файлы.

> как они работают?

В Ubuntu есть встроенная система бэкапа. Зайдите

*Параметры системы / Резервные копии*

Там задаёте что нужно бэкапить, с какой частотой и куда. Очень важно, по максимум, задать список того, что исключаем из бэкапа. Это сильно облегчает процесс.

Большим преимуществом такого решения является то, что оно встроено в дистрибутив. Если вы случайно удалили файл, но он был в бэкапе, то он элементарно восстанавливается:

- Запускаем файловый менеджер
- Заходим в каталог, где был удалённый файл
- Щёлкаем правой мышкой
- Выбираем "Восстановление отсутствующих файлов"

Кто сталкивался с проблемой случайно удалённого файла в люникс, то оценит эту способность! :-)

> 3. разве не могут быть случаи, когда некоторые приложения часть своих файлов не в /home

Вообще-то, люних - это НЕ виндовоз! Если вы лично не приложили титанических усилий, что бы испортить себе жизнь, то такая ситуация **абсолютно** невозможна. Никакой пользователь (кроме root) не имеет доступа в чужие/системные каталоги и ничего там хранить не может. И даже внутри */home* Вы имеете доступ только к */hone/my_name*.

При работе любой программы (к примеру - FireFox) все временные файлы, кэши и даунлоад сохраняются **только** в домашнем каталоге пользователя.

Ну и последнее замечание. Если вы не захотите использовать стандартный сервис Ubuntu, то, проще всего воспользоваться командой *tar* для сброса домашнего каталога на флешку:

```
$ tar -cvjf /media/<Здесь Ваш логин>/<Метка тома флэшки>/backup.bz2 ~/<Каталог бэкапа>
```